# How to include DLL in Netbeans?

Tags: dll, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I have a  Java webservice running on a Glassfish server that uses JDBC with WindowsAuthentication to connect to a SQL Server database so it needs the sqljdbc_auth dll. I've copied that dll to the glassfish bin folder and it works when I start the server.

My problem is that when I make changes to the code in NetBeans and deploy the webservice it doesn't work anymore (saying is not configured for windows authentication), I guess that happens because it is not including the dll. How can I include it in NetBeans? I've placed the DLL in the root of the project but it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by placing the sqljdbc4.jar in the glassfish lib folder too (rather than importing only in NetBeans).